# What size could be a gigantic water Pokémon?

Tags: gm-preparation

I'm going to be a GM with 3 players, and we will be playing with the Pokémon Tabletop United rules.

In these rules, there's a whole part about Shiny Pokémon, that aren't just Pokémon with another set of colours like in the games. I had an idea that a Wailord, the biggest Pokémon, could have somehow mutated to become even more bigger. What I want is that Wailord to come at the surface and everyone would think it's an island because of its size.

Problem is: I have a player that I think will tell me things like "How could it be that big? How can it swim in the ocean? Why did nobody see that it was a Wailord?"

So I'd like to know what could be a good size for a giant Wailord to be mistaken for an island, so there's some things to explore and discover, but not too oversized to be somehow realistic?

Comment: IIRC there are a number of Pokémon in the anime that are of unusual size or complexion, so there is precedence.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs The only ones I can think of were robots, in the first season... But I stopped at the 3rd or 4th season. Still, I'd like it to be a little realistic, and not just "Shhh, it's Pokémon, just catch it and let it go"

Comment: I think that's actually what you should do in this situation. There are still wonders in the world of Pokémon that will never quite be explained, and massive Pokémon can very well be one of them.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Well, that's too bad :( I'll wait a little and see if anyone comes up with anything, and if not... Let's just say that "It's Pokémon" will become my new "It's magic".

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting beyond "the size of an island (pick whatever size of island you want) or like twice as big so you only see part of it"? Calculating wailord sizes based on a certain exposed shape is not really in our site's purview nor do I see it being necessary for an RPG. "It's big, it's really huge" and descriptions of how huge usually do more for anyone than kilometer and metre measurements of anatomy.

Comment: @doppelgreener Well, something that would be explaining why X square-meters is too wide because the Wailord would be too big to swim, or X square-meters are too little to explore anything... Or even some tricks I could use to make it looks like it's bigger than it is, or to make my players search more. And to answer your edit: I want to make sure that I could come up with anything for my player if he thinks the Wailord's too big. One kilometer is REALLY huge for an animal, and I'm not sure it could even move or live or not create any disaster.

Comment: A creature big enough to be mistaken for an island is already bigger than [the biggest earth mammal currently alive](http://twistedsifter.com/2012/04/15-of-the-largest-animals-in-the-world/), and beyond that you're asking about a pokemon. Realism is kinda off the table here. What you might be concerned with is how big you can make it before you break immersion, which I don't think is something we can have a definite answer for. If you want a strict anatomical calculation for how big a whale can get, you might want to seek out [biology.se] or [worldbuilding.se] something.